# How to split a tolist result in two groups (new lists)?

Tags: python, dataframe, split, drop, isin

I have a problem, I try many things and I can't manage to do this.
It's a code that check if the delivery numbers are on our sales report.

Here it's the code:

```
dfn = dfn.astype('str')
diff = dfn[~dfn['Numero de Envio'].isin(dfn['Unnamed: 13'])].dropna()[['Numero de Envio','Fecha']].values.tolist() 
print(f"\n Hay ventas que podrían no ser nuestras: \U0001F611 - Revisar :" '\n')
diff
```

The result is:

```
[['piedras blancas', '2022-12-01'],
 ['41845010982', '2022-12-01'],
 ['carrasco norte', '2022-12-05'],
 ['41855309788', '2022-12-05'],
 ['villa española ', '2022-12-07'],
 ['aires puros', '2022-12-08'],
 ['monica villa borges', '2022-12-08'],
 ['nicolas diego ', '2022-12-08'],
 ['enrique permuy', '2022-12-08'],
 ['natalia blanco', '2022-12-08'],
 ['laurita', '2022-12-09'],
 ['hugo carrion', '2022-12-10'],
 ['4187289809', '2022-12-12'],
 ['mariana', '2022-12-12'],
 ['amelia vignolo', '2022-12-14'],
 ['leonardo saucedo', '2022-12-14'],
 ['14891993727', '2022-12-17'],
 ['maria noel dottone', '2022-12-19'],
 ['41899599250', '2022-12-19'],
 ['41898783286', '2022-12-19'],
 ['corpo pilates ltd', '2022-12-19'],
 ['serrana bentancour', '2022-12-20'],
 ['fabiana lima', '2022-12-21'],
 ['41916589225', '2022-12-26'],
 ['41917845465', '2022-12-26'],
 ['41916895866', '2022-12-26'],
 ['41917386564', '2022-12-26'],
 ['41917285884', '2022-12-26'],
 ['41900719115', '2022-12-27'],
 ['mauro gonzalez', '2022-12-27']]
```

I want to split in two groups: The ones that start with numbers and the other the names, my expected result is:

```
['41845010982', '2022-12-01']          
['41899599250', '2022-12-19'],
['41898783286', '2022-12-19']
['41916589225', '2022-12-26'],
['41917845465', '2022-12-26'],
['41916895866', '2022-12-26'],
['41917386564', '2022-12-26'],
['41917285884', '2022-12-26'],
['41900719115', '2022-12-27'],


['villa española ', '2022-12-07'],
['aires puros', '2022-12-08'],
['monica villa borges', '2022-12-08'],
['nicolas diego ', '2022-12-08'],
['enrique permuy', '2022-12-08'],
['natalia blanco', '2022-12-08'],
['laurita', '2022-12-09'],
['hugo carrion', '2022-12-10'],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution would be to use [`GroupBy.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with [`pandas.Series.isnumeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.isnumeric.html) :

```
for m, g in diff.groupby(diff.apply(lambda x: x[0]).str.isnumeric()):
    if m:
        listOfNumbers = g.tolist()
    else:
        listOfStrings = g.tolist()
```

Output :

```
print(listOfNumbers)

[['41845010982', '2022-12-01'],
 ['41855309788', '2022-12-05'],
 ['4187289809', '2022-12-12'],
 ...


print(listOfStrings)

[['piedras blancas', '2022-12-01'],
 ['carrasco norte', '2022-12-05'],
 ['villa española ', '2022-12-07'],
 ...
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with two for loops:

```
# prints all numbers
for i in diff:
    if i[0].isnumeric():
        print(i)

print('') # new line

# prints all non-numbers
for i in diff:
    if not i[0].isnumeric():
        print(i)
```

Comment: The second instance is not working in (syntax error) : if !i[0].isnumeric():

Comment: Ah yes forgot there isn't `!` in python XD

Comment: I don't understand why this answer was accepted and upvoted when 1. it does not work 2. it does not attempt to produce the required separated lists.

Comment: 1. it does work, I tested it out 2. The OP didn't ask to make separated lists, but to __print__ the numbers and non-number keyed stuff separetly